# problema datepicker

Tags: laravel-5

Buen dia

He tratado de configurar un datepicker en mi formulario pero no ha sido posible, si el codigo se ejecuta en una sola plantilla como esta https://paste.laravel.io/e7e39b0d-2d6b-423c-a26f-4d1e3050e116,  funciona sin problemas,

Pero en mi caso, tengo un layout y una vista, he tratado de integrar esto pero no funciona, esto es lo que he tratado de hacer.

layout https://paste.laravel.io/4f3ec730-d8be-426c-924e-7ab32daf1e53
vista https://paste.laravel.io/ba4e77e2-dbc4-45db-9ee5-4126f53b3ee3

Como puedo adaptar esto?

Comment: Si puedes coloca el codigo aca, algun error?

Comment: El codigo esta en los link que publique, sin embargo en esta url esta lo que pretendo, el error es muy simple en mi caso, y es que cuando doy clic al input no aparece el calendario, como sale aqui  http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Comment: Si, pero me referia si verificaste en la consola del navegador a ver si esta leyendo las librerias correctamente.

Comment: Ese es el punto.. no las lee.. por que tengo un layout y una vista, no se como hacer para que funcione, ya que en el ejemplo funciona pero todo esta en una sola plantilla

Comment: Pon el código generado, el que ves en el navegador cuando accedes. De todos modos, veo en la parte de la vista, en la que extiendes del layout, que informas la sección `content` pero no veo que definas esa sección en el layout